# Is it good reputation for a researcher to publish an article belonging to different research field?

Tags: publications, self-promotion

I have a BA in International Relations and  MA in Water Management which is the field I want to do research. However recently one of my former professors in my current workplace asking me for colloboration in research related to international relations. Now I am in a difficult position as I do not know what to do. Do you think it is okay to have this kind of publication?

Comment: Many times, having an interdisciplinary view is considered positively these days. It may depend on the specifics of the research topic, but I see a lot of possibilities for combining international relations and water management.

Comment: If the paper is good, then having the publication is good.  If the paper is bad, then having the publication is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the fields are so far apart, a publication in one might not help you in the other, specifically. However getting some research experience is both worth the effort and will be looked on positively. In addition to being relevant to some field, research involves a process requiring focus and discipline.

I'd only recommend against this if the time involved would take you away from your mainline trajectory.

The publication won't hurt you. The experience will help. But it takes time and effort.